# Entity Framework: Indexing a child entity based on a value on the parent entity for uniqueness

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, data-annotations, entity-relationship, unique-constraint

I have a quick question and looking for the best way to do this, whether EF has the capability or not, am not sure? I am using EntityFramework 6.3.

I have the following parent-child scenario,

```
public class Application{
 [Key]
 public int ApplicationId {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public string Status {get;set;}

 public virtual List<Document> Documents {get;set;}
}

public class Document{
 [Key]
 public int DocumentId {get;set;}
 [Index("IX_ApplicationDocument", 1, IsUnique = true)]
 public string DocumentType {get;set;}
 [Index("IX_ApplicationDocument", 1, IsUnique = true)]
 public string Name {get;set;}

 public int ApplicationId {get;set;}

 [ForeignKey("ApplicationId")]
 public Application Application {get;set;}
}
```

So an application is made to a department, and stored in the database, each application has a status and when submitted, status of pending, because various  validation has to occur before it is approved. When an application is rejected, the submitter has to make a new application (please note I used a minimalistic example than what it actually is), however, the applicant may submit the same documents again. The problem is, this already exist in the system and can not be duplicated. As you can see, the second time they attempt to submit it will throw a constraint exception. How can I overcome this using EF, is there a way to create a constraint based on the parent's status, or is this something that can only be done programmatically?

Comment: can you clarify a bit, you want documentId to be unique for future but ok to be duplicate for existing?

Comment: basically, if you want to avoid duplicate for new entries then you can create a filtered unique index on SQL Server using Entity Framework. let me know if this is the case

Answer (score 1):

Dont know if its helps you in your case or not, but check this out

Assuming your entity is defined as

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Parent { get; set; }
    public int Child { get; set; }
}
```

Following fluent API code will create index as you desire:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>().HasIndex(p => new {p.Parent, p.Child})
        .HasFilter("isdeleted = 0")
        .HasName("unq_t_parent_child");
```

SQL generated

```
CREATE INDEX [unq_t_parent_child] ON [Entity] ([Parent], [Child]) WHERE isdeleted = 0;
```

**HasIndex** defines index over properties in the table Entity

**HasFilter** allows you to set a filter for your index. This value is sql so you need to make sure you are writing correct sql syntax.

**HasName** configures the name of the index.

(If you map Entity to table t & the properties to their column names, migrations will create exactly same sql as you want.)

Also a check constraint is different from unique index. If you are looking to add check constraint then you need to use migrationBuilder.Sql in your migration file.

Comment: Oh my, exactly what I have been looking for, I know you could do this in Oracle, just was not sure how to do it from a coding perspective. Thank you so much @Syed_Wahhab. This is a great eye opener to a lot of scenarios I have had :-)

Comment: One question, isdeleted, is this a propery of the entity or a reserved word?

Comment: No donny 'isdeleted' is not a property of EF.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is for EntityFramework Core, and did specify the version I'm using :-( I am using EntityFramework 6.3.

Answer (score 0):

So unfortunately I have searched around and there is no solution for this for EF 6. The best way I can do this was following the guidance of the following article, where you manually add the Filtered Index in your migration after table creation.

[Blog](https://justsimplycode.com/2016/01/30/creating-unique-filtered-index-using-code-first-in-entity-framework-6/)